# `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'

Tags: python, numpy

I want to learn a code and I to run this code,

```
def __init__( self, input=None, input_history=None, n_visible=7,
                 n_hidden=500, delay=6, A=None, B=None, W=None, hbias=None,
                 vbias=None, numpy_rng=None):

        self.n_visible = n_visible
        self.n_hidden = n_hidden
        self.delay = delay

        if numpy_rng is None:

            numpy_rng = numpy.random.RandomState(1234)

        if W is None:

            W = np.asarray(0.01 * numpy_rng.randn(n_visible,
                                                          n_hidden))

        if A is None:
            A = np.asarray(0.01 * numpy_rng.randn(n_visible * delay,
                                                           n_visible))

        if B is None:
            B = np.asarray(0.01 * numpy_rng.randn(n_visible * delay,
                                                           n_hidden))

        if hbias is None:

            hbias = numpy.zeros(n_hidden)

        if vbias is None:

            vbias = numpy.zeros(n_visible)


        self.input = input     
        self.input_history = input_history
        self.W = W
        self.A = A
        self.B = B
        self.hbias = hbias
        self.vbias = vbias

        self.numpy_rng = numpy_rng


def propup(self, vis, v_history):

            pre_sigmoid_activation = numpy.dot(vis, self.W) + \
                                     numpy.dot(v_history, self.B) + self.hbias
            return sigmoid(pre_sigmoid_activation)
```

but I get an error message,

> `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'

if anyone can explain the intent of this :'NoneType' and 'float'. And do I have to change my data? 
but earlier I did not find any error while doing this code

```
def propup(self, vis):
    pre_sigmoid_activation = numpy.dot(vis, self.W) + self.hbias
    return sigmoid(pre_sigmoid_activation)
```

I'm not sure if this code is causing the above problem?

```
def get_cost_updates(self, lr=0.1, k=1):

        ph_mean, ph_sample = \
                        self.sample_h_given_v(self.input, self.input_history)


        chain_start = ph_sample

        for step in range(k):
           if step == 0:
             nv_means, nv_samples,\
             nh_means, nh_samples = self.gibbs_hvh(chain_start)
           else:
             nv_means, nv_samples,\
             nh_means, nh_samples = self.gibbs_hvh(nh_samples)

        self.W += lr * (numpy.dot(self.input.T, ph_mean)
                    - numpy.dot(nv_samples.T, nh_means))
        self.vbias += lr * numpy.mean(self.input - nv_samples, self.input_history, axis=0)
        self.hbias += lr * numpy.mean(ph_mean - nh_means, self.input_history, axis=0)

        monitoring_cost = numpy.mean(numpy.square(self.input - nv_means))

        return monitoring_cost
```

Comment: Please see [mcve]. If we can't reproduce the error, it's a lot harder to see the mistake.

Comment: I've added some variables @zondo

Answer (score -1):

use colon(:) at the end of function declaration. It is basic syntax error.

def propup(self, vis, v_history):

pre_sigmoid_activation = numpy.dot(vis, self.W) + \
                                     numpy.dot(v_history, self.B) + self.hbias
            return sigmoid(pre_sigmoid_activation)

Comment: Then check your input. because from your given code there is no other errors. What is your input??

Comment: if according to initial codes without self.input history data I have no problem. I will input the data matrix and vector (float and int) that I made in tuples, @Dhruvil Shah

Comment: if __init__ function used in other function then try to add return statement in init function.

Comment: Is not that  __init__() should return None? @Dhruvil Shah